# jQuery css transition callback firing multiple times

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu animation issue. Why does the `slideDown` transition happen twice. [See JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/uyf5j5h8/6/).

```
<ul class=top-menu">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li>Sub Item 1</li>
         ....
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Hover on the black vertical menu bar and it will slide out and a sub menu slide down.

I have the following code to ensure that the menu first opens to the right, then the slide down takes place for any selected sub menu.

```
$('#page-wrapper').one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.active ul:first').slideDown('normal');
});
```

Why does `slideDown` execute twice?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It would help if you created a demo.  Have you tried `$('.active ul:first').stop().slideDown('normal');`?

Comment: Hi @sideroxylon you are right, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/uyf5j5h8/6/

Comment: your side menu is not completely hidden? you want it like this only?

Comment: Hi @Siddharth, on "small" just the icons are visible, one "open" you can see the text too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop animations in progress before starting the new one:

```
$('.active ul:first').stop().slideDown('normal')
```

Comment: hi @sideroxylon thanks but it did not solve the issue. It is somehow (now) triggering the `slideDown` twice in the `.hover` function. Cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Listen do something like this, when you click on `span.menu-toggle-screen` you add some class(`.random`) to `div#sidebar-wrapper`, and when in

```
$("div#sidebar-wrapper").hover(
  function(e) {
  /* check if your div wrapper has the `random` class, if yes return false and terminate the call back */


    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("toggled-2")) {

      //$('.active ul:first').stop().slideDown('normal');

      /* Slide down any sub-menus after the main transition stops */
      $('#page-wrapper').one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(e) {
        $('.active ul:first').stop().slideDown('normal');
      });

    }
  },
```